# Javascript Highcharts cannot get the name of the click column in the onclick event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get the name of the column that it's clicked but I get undefined.

I can see that it shows in the tooltip but not when I click the column.

Here's the code:

```
$(function () {

var data = { "mains": [{ "id": "454", "name": "main 1", "subs": [{ "id": "32", "name": "sub 1" }, { "id": "23", "name": "sub 2" }, { "id": "54", "name": "sub 3" }], "image": null }, { "id": "654", "name": "main 2", "subs": [{ "id": "87", "name": "sub 1" }, { "id": "78", "name": "sub 2" }], "image": null }] };


mainlist = [],
sublist = Object.create(null);

data.mains.forEach(function (main) {
    mainlist.push(main.name);
    sublist[main.name] = main.subs.map(function (sub) {
        return sub.name;
    });
})


$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Top Title Here'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: mainlist
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Left Title',
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {

                        alert(this.name); //returns undefined

                    },
                },
            },
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'title here',
        data: [5, 10]
    }],

});
```

I have also tried this.series.name, this.x and this.y but none are giving me the name.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the doc states the *[plotOptions.series.point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click)* only gets an *event* as parameter within its event-listeners, nevertheless they hold some info as well:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Top Title Here'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: mainlist
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Left Title',
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    // a click-listener gets an event as param
                    click: function (event) {

                        console.log(event.point.category); //returns "main 1" or "main 2"
                        console.log(event.point.plotX+'/'+event.point.plotY); //or its coords

                        console.log(event);// and a lot more

                    },
                },
            },
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'title here',
        data: [5, 10]
    }],

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the "events" object inside the "column" object instead series.